# Button onClick add value to ArrayAdapter array

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to figure out how to add another string to my month array and display that in a list view dynamically via pressing the button. Currently I have no problem display the array I have specified, but I cant figure out a way to add my count variable which should be added to the array list after the button is clicked. Any ideas ? Thank's for the help!!!!

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
        OnItemClickListener {

    Button test;
        ListView list;
    String month[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    public static int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        test.setOnClickListener(this);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tlist);
        list.setAdapter(new  ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, month));
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            count++;

            //Add count value to end of array
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when u click on the button, update the contents of your array { in your case month[], say add month to it } then call "ListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();" whenre ListAdapter is your custom adapter. Basically notifyDataSetChanged will call getview of your adapter and it will update the list

Comment: myArr.add("" + count);
   ArrayAdapter<String> myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myArr);
   list.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
   myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();